# Unable to escape some characters in a Unix command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ubuntu

I'm trying to coinfigure `iwatch` to monitor a directory for changes to some files. It seems to be quote simple but I'm having issues escaping the command string. Here's an example:

```
 iwatch -r -x '\.git' -t 'django\.po' -c 'echo ''Hello''' -e modify ./myapplication/locale/
```

This monitors the `/myapplication/locale/` for all `*.po` files excluding the `.git` directories and when a file is modified, it runs the command `echo 'Hello'`.

...but when I try using a command that is a slightly more complex, I get errors:

```
 iwatch -r -x '\.git' -t 'django\.po' -c 'echo git pull && whoami' -e modify ./myapplication/locale/
```

The command `git pull && whoami` is a valid Unix command but I think I need to escape it somehow for it to work. I get errors at the part where there's a the `&&`

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

---

Edit #1: Trying Michael's suggestion:

```
iwatch -r -x '\.git' -t 'django\.po' -c "bash -c 'git pull && whoami'" -e modify ./giosg-chat/locale/
```

...and here's the error.

```
:5: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name
    <path type="recursive" events="modify" exec="bash -c 'git pull && whoami'" a
                                                                    ^
:5: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name
    <path type="recursive" events="modify" exec="bash -c 'git pull && whoami'" a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the command string is being processed using some sort of XML and in XML, all ampersands need to be escaped. Here's a discussion:

http://lists.xml.org/archives/xml-dev/200106/msg00223.html

This worked:

```
iwatch -r -x '\.git' -t 'django\.po' -c 'echo git pull &amp;&amp; whoami' -e modify ./myapplication/locale/
```

Answer (score 1):

`git pull && whoami` is not a 'valid UNIX command' as you say it is.  The `&&` is a shell operation that is almost certainly not supported by the `-c` flag of `iwatch`.  A workaround might be to write a script that does the compound operation and then to pass that script as the argument to the `-c` flag.

Comment: Or you can use `iwatch -c "bash -c 'git pull && whoami'"`

Comment: +1 @Michael, that's a good solution that doesn't involve an external script.

Comment: That doesn't work either. Please have a look at my edit. It seems like there's some kind of XML parser in the background that fails upon encountering these characters. :|

Comment: Solved it. Please look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the shell, inside single quotes, there are no special characters and the first single quote (after the starting one) ends the single quotes.  That means that your invocation shown first does not do quite what you think:

```
iwatch -r -x '\.git' -t 'django\.po' -c 'echo ''Hello''' \
    -e modify ./myapplication/locale/
```

The `iwatch` command actually sees the same as if you typed:

```
iwatch -r -x '\.git' -t 'django\.po' -c 'echo Hello' \
    -e modify ./myapplication/locale/
```

So, what the shell runs is actually:

```
echo Hello
```

and not

```
echo 'Hello'
```

There's no difference in the output; there is a difference in the input.  To spot the difference, you'd need to have spacing in the input including double spaces, such as:

```
-c 'echo ''Hello  Double  Spaced  World'''
```

which would output the value with single spaces.  If you actually want to get single quotes around 'Hello' to `iwatch`, you'd have to write:

```
iwatch -r -x '\.git' -t 'django\.po' -c 'echo '\''Hello'\''' \
   -e modify ./myapplication/locale/
```

or:

```
iwatch -r -x '\.git' -t 'django\.po' -c 'echo '\''Hello'\' \
   -e modify ./myapplication/locale/
```

The magic incantation `'\''` means:

- close the current single-quoted string
- include a single quote (that's the backslash and the next single quote)
- restart the single-quoted string

In the first of the examples, the next character is the end of the single quoted string again; the second does away with the two adjacent single quotes.

You could demonstrate that this works with:

```
-c 'echo '\''Hello  Double  Spaced  World'\'
```

which would output the value with double spaces (unless something in `iwatch` subverted the system).

---

Since you've now found the problem - that the command is treated as XML and you have to use `&amp;` to get ampersands to the shell - what I said is mainly of academic importance.